# Show that $x=Re(z)$, and $y=Im(z)$ are not complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I am self-learning Gamelin’s Complex Analysis and I have performed a calculation w.r.t ex. 3 on p. 46 and I ended ip misinterpreting my conclusion and now I’d love some feedback.

The exercise is to show from the definition of the complex derivative that the functions $x=Re(z)$, and $y=Im(z)$ are not complex differentiable at any point in $\mathbb{C}$.

I started out like this: $$1+ i0=1=\lim_{z\to z_0} 1=\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{z-z_0}{z-z_0}=\lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{Re(z)-Re(z_0)}{z-z_0} + i \lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{Im(z) - Im(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$

Identifying real and imaginary parts we obtain $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{Re(z)-Re(z_0)}{z-z_0} = 1$, and $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{Im(z)-Im(z_0)}{z-z_0} = 0$.

Now, I am unsure what my result means or if it means anything at all?

Thank you in advance, 
Isak

Comment: This should be as simple as noting that the Cauchy-Riemann equations fail _everywhere_.

Comment: You cannot use the equation $\lim (a_n+b_n) =\lim a_n+\lim b_n$ without knowing that the limits exist. Use C-R equations as suggested in above comment.

Comment: Thank you, I have, however, not covered CR-equations yet. Is there another way to interpret my result? My guess is that the characteristics of $Re(z)$ and $Im(z)$ should be the same since they are the same ’type’ of functions, and since they lead to different values of their limits it would mean they are not complex differentiable in the first place?

Comment: " if it means anything at all? " is the right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a synthesis of the other answers and comments and this synthesis is what I personally think makes up a complete answer to what the OP was asking for.

The functions $x=\mathbb{Re}(z)$ and $y=\mathbb{Im}(z)$ are not complex differentiable at any point in $\mathbb{C}$ because their limits (of the corresponding complex derivative) do not match up at any point in $\mathbb{C}$.

Actually, since $\Delta z \to 0$ along many paths in $\mathbb{C}$ we calculate $\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{\mathbb{Re}(z+\Delta z) - \mathbb{Re}(z)}{\Delta z}$ and $\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{\mathbb{Im}(z+\Delta z) - \mathbb{Im}(z)}{\Delta z}$ as $\Delta z = \Delta x$ and when $\Delta z = i\Delta y$.

This gives $$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{\mathbb{Re}(z+\Delta z) - \mathbb{Re}(z)}{\Delta z} = \begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } \Delta z = \Delta x\\
    0,              & \text{if} \Delta z = i\Delta y
\end{cases}$$

and, $$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{\mathbb{Im}(z+\Delta z) - \mathbb{Im}(z)}{\Delta z} = \begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } \Delta z = \Delta x\\
   -i,              & \text{if} \Delta z = i\Delta y
\end{cases}$$

So the OP imposes a restriction to the real line when OP is assuming that $\lim(a_n+b_n)= \lim(a_n)+\lim(b_n)$ without knowing that the individual limits exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z, h \in \mathbb{C}, h \neq 0$. Then $$\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z+h)- \operatorname{Re}(z)}{h} = \frac{\operatorname{Re}(z) + \operatorname{Re}(h)- \operatorname{Re}(z)}{h} = \frac{\operatorname{Re}(h)}{h}.$$
Now you can look at the sequences $a_n := \frac{1}{n}, b_n := \frac{i}{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ and observe that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$$ but $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\operatorname{Re}(a_n)}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{a_n} = 1 \neq 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{0}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\operatorname{Re}(b_n)}{b_n},$$ so the limit $\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z+h)- \operatorname{Re}(z)}{h}$ as $h \to 0$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ be a real number.

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Re(z+h)-\Re(z)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}h\ne\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Re(z+ih)-\Re(z)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0}h$$

and simlarly for $\Im(z)$.